# How to change mouse cursor within Toggle button

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ToggleButton and when clicking this button, the processing time could take a while, like 3 to 5 seconds. During that time, I'd like to give a feedback to the user changing the cursor to the Wait state.

The click of the ToggleButton is handled by a Command, because I'm using the MVVM pattern so, I don't handle the click event and can't change that using code behind.

Is there a way to that using only xaml?

I tried this but it does not work:

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptureWithin" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Wait"></Setter>
  </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Wouldn't rather just use a busy indicator?

Comment: Which control is the style for?

Comment: As it says it questions, it's a ToggleButton with a command. The command takes a long time to execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the IsChecked property on the ToggleButton to your ViewModel or use a Command, when the value changes or the command is executed you can change a second Property (call it something like IsBusy). Then create a DataTrigger like:

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBusy}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Wait"></Setter>
  </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```